# My Asus laptop freezes randomly

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, freeze

I own Asus R558U laptop (hardware details at the bottom of my post)
Couple of months ago it started freezing completly during random situations.
Recently I decided to observe it more closely and try different hardware and software configurations in order to rule out some possibilities.
I was unable to see any pattern though.
I have searched and read many articles looking for the solution already with no success.

**Frequency:**
once every couple of days
I think it has increased over time

**Symptoms:**

- laptop completely frozen (always)
- strange buzzing sound (sometimes)
- graphics artifacts (sometimes)

**Visible on the following operating systems (I use dual boot):**

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Windows 10

**During the following activities:**

- watching movies
- internet browsing
- image editing
- programming
- even when left idle

**Here is what I have already tried and checked:**

- Temperature - It seems not to be a problem. Here is the output from sensors program collected when I rebooted right after the freeze:

  ```
  coretemp-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  Package id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
  Core 0:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
  Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

  acpitz-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

  asus-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  cpu_fan:     3500 RPM
  temp1:        +48.0°C  

  pch_skylake-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +47.5°C
  ```
- smart data & self-tests from disks utility - everything was ok
- memtest86 - everything was ok

**My peripherals and wireless adapters when I observed the problem:**

- wifi was always on
- usb remote keyboard + mouse always plugged (tried
  different usb ports though)
- bluetooth on or off
- external monitor
  plugged or unplugged (vga cable)
- usb drive plugged or unplugged
- powercable plugged or unplugged
- headset plugged or unplugged

**Detailed hardware information:**

```
$ hwinfo --short
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2600 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2600 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2600 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2600 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event6    Logitech Unifying Receiver
  /dev/input/event3    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      Logitech Unifying Receiver
  /dev/input/mice      Asus TouchPad
monitor:
                       LG Display LCD Monitor
                       DELL U2412M
graphics card:
                       Intel HD Graphics 520
                       nVidia GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
sound:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
storage:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
network:
  wlp3s0               Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  enp2s0               Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  wlp3s0               Ethernet network interface
  enp2s0               Ethernet network interface
  pan1                 Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             A SP550
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda3            Partition
  /dev/sda4            Partition
  /dev/sda5            Partition
  /dev/sda6            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr0             HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUE1N
usb controller:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       IMC Networks Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PMC
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
                       Intel Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
  /dev/input/event9    Realtek USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
                       Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller



sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device      Class          Description
=====================================================
                           system         X556UQ (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
/0                         bus            X556UQ
/0/0                       memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/11                      memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/12                      memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/13                      memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/14                      memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/15                      processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
/0/16                      memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/16/0                    memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/16/1                    memory         [empty]
/0/16/2                    memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/16/3                    memory         [empty]
/0/100                     bridge         Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                   display        HD Graphics 520
/0/100/4                   generic        Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                  bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0    usb1        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2              input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/5              generic        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/14/0/6              multimedia     USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
/0/100/14/0/8              communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1    usb2        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/15                  generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                  communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                  storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1c                  bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0                display        GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
/0/100/1c.4                bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0  enp2s0      network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.5                bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
/0/100/1c.5/0  wlp3s0      network        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1f                  bridge         Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/1           scsi0       storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda    disk           240GB ADATA SP550
/0/1/0.0.0/1   /dev/sda1   volume         259MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2   volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3   volume         125GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4   /dev/sda4   volume         498MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5   /dev/sda5   volume         46GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/6   /dev/sda6   volume         51GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2           scsi1       storage        
/0/2/0.0.0     /dev/cdrom  disk           DVDRAM GUE1N
/1             pan1        network        Ethernet interface
```

Could you please give any advice? Maybe you already have encountered such problems?

Comment: Random problems of low frequency are very hard to solve via a Q&A site.  You may get some diagnostic suggestions, but this isn't something that has a definitive answer that can be known from the available information.

Comment: Well, on a good note you have tried 3 OS's and two distinctly different ones, so the issue is likely not software meaning you have narrowed down half the possible issues. The issues just prior to or when it occurs are often related to RAM or CPU, so I would start there. You have 2 DIMMs so remove one and run it for a while to isolate if one DIMM is bad over time (unusual but possible). Again, this is a very difficult issue to troubleshoot since you can't duplicate it with any consistency in a reasonable time frame, not really the kind of stuff we deal with here.

Comment: @acejavelin, I will experiment with my DIMMs as you suggested.

Comment: @acejavelin, I removed one of my DIMM's like five days ago, and I haven't seen the problem since then. I will continue testing, but it seems promising.

Comment: @PiotrKózka Are your DIMMs a matched pair?

Comment: @acejavelin They are identical in terms of size and frequency. The difference is that one of them is soldered into the motherboard.

Comment: @PiotrKózka Hmm... I don't think this laptop has soldered RAM.

Comment: @acejavelin It has. Anyway I continued with one DIMM removed, and I've not experienced this issue anymore since the DIMM removal.